# Replace cache path on selected objects (Maya+Python)

Tags: python, maya

Hi, I need to repath a lot of cache files in Maya but I'm not being able to access the cache attributes to select cache path base directory and set it to the final cache folder. Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution to get path for abc cache :

```
shape = cmds.ls(sl=True, dag=True, type="mesh", ni=True) # just to get the mesh shape under selection
abc = cmds.listConnections(shape, type='AlembicNode') # find the alembic node
cache_path = cmds.getAttr('{0}.{1}'.format(abc[0],'abc_File') ) # get the path
```

for geo cache, attributes are both :

.cacheName
.cachePath